# SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server, Django and AWS SES

Tags: python, django, email, amazon-ses

I am trying to send an email via AWS SES with tls enabled. SES requires tls to be enabled. However when I set my smtp connection to use tls I get this exception. And when I do not set `use_tls` to `True` I get another exception stating **tls** is required to use ses.

#### Code

```
from django.core.mail import get_connection  #1
# msg composed
connection = get_connection()                #2
connection.use_tls = True                    #3
connection.send_messages([msg, ])            #4
```

#### Error Traceback:

> File "/home/myproject/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/mail/backends/smtp.py", line 51, in open
>       self.connection.starttls()
>     File "/usr/lib/python2.7/smtplib.py", line 635, in starttls
>       raise SMTPException("STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
>   SMTPException: STARTTLS extension not supported by server

Comment: Are you sure you're connecting to the right port? Notice [STARTTLS and SMTP over SSL are different things](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STARTTLS#SSL_ports). While STARTTLS is usually available on the standard SMTP port (25), SMTP over SSL is usually available at port 465

Comment: @goncalopp: I tried each of 587, 465 and 25. These are the only SMTP port options that I see in SES. All of them give the same error.

Comment: I guess it could be a temporary problem with Amazon SES, as it started working now.

Comment: For port 465 (smtps) you have to use use_ssl, not use_tls. use_tls is for STARTTLS only (i.e. upgrade plain connection to SSL), but smtps connects directly with SSL.